# Criar propriedade personalizada no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Olá quero fazer o seguinte, utilizo data types para criar propriedades personalizáveis, porém queria fazer como o VueJS ele tem v-model v-on entre outros essa propriedades e criada usando HTMLElement?

Comment: @Sergio você entendeu mesmo a pergunta? Eu não. Matheus, você quer fazer algo no Vue, ou fazer por conta próprio parecido com o Vue?

Comment: @bfavaretto para mim é claro o problema, uma app que usa datatypes (atributos `data-`), daí a minha sugestão de usar o `v-bind`.  Mas posso claro estar errado.

Comment: Eu acho que ele quer implementar um mecanismo reativo por conta própria, @Sergio. Ele diz "porém queria fazer como o VueJS".

Comment: @bfavaretto ok, como disse, posso estar enganado. Vamos ver o que o Matheus diz.

Comment: Matheus lê os comentários acima ^. Se a minha resposta estiver errada não a aceites, para podermos esclarecer e dar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Olá, a resposta ficou com duplo sentido kkk, más enfim eu queria mesmo e fazer igual o VueJS por conta própria ( fazer um componente reativo )

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar o `v-bind` para passar um objeto ao template que vai registar no HTML esses atributos.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
 new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     customProps: {
       'data-foo': 100,
       'data-bar': 'algo'
     },
     message: 'Olá Vue.js!'
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-bind="customProps">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

E o HTML resultante é:

```html
 <p data-foo="100" data-bar="algo">Olá Hello Vue.js!</p>
```

Comment: Pode não ser o que ele está perguntando, mas aprendi uma coisa nova com a sua resposta! :)